# Memory error when kniting in R

Tags: r

I try to knit an `Rdata` file in `R studio` and get an error that cannot allocate vector `1,8mb`.

I understand that I have memory issue so I tried to use `memory.limit()` as suggested on another post but I got an error

> memory.size() is Windows-specific.

I also made extra RAM using a `usb` and changing `swappiness` but nothing happened. I'm using `Ubuntu 14.04 32bit`, `R Version 3.3.0 32bit` and also I have Windows O/S installed.

Comment: Is it really "1,8mb" and not "1,8GB"? Please copy the error message and put it in your question, i.e. edit your question: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37593942/edit  Further: what is your system, Ubuntu or Windows or 'Windows on Ubuntu' or 'Ubuntu on Windows'?

Comment: It's not uncommon that this sort of error is produced because of some fault in the code. Because this is very murky topic, it's hard to be specific. Have you tried running the code on a different computer, system or architecture?

Comment: No I haven't run it on any other computer

Comment: Please make the example reproducible or at least provide a more informative and complete statement on your error

Comment: @jogo Rstudio starts kniting and the in a specific line the process ends and the error I get is :"Error in line 99", "Error cannot allocate vector size 1,8MB.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're on a 32-bit installation of R and you've used up the (very small) amount of memory it can handle. If you just switch to 64-bit you won't get this error.

The error message is because you invoked a Windows-specific command on Ubuntu, but that's really not relevant because with 32-bit R there's a hard limit on memory which you've already hit.

I know this is confusing because it's complaining about a very small size vector (1.8 MB) but that just means that the remaining amount of memory 32-bit R can handle is less than that.

If you were on Windows you *might* need to set the memory limit *in addition* to using 64-bit R, but if you're using Ubuntu then just using 64-bit R should solve the problem.

**RStudio Instructions**

I'm basing this on my version of RStudio, yours might be slightly different but it should be very close.

1. Click `Tools`
2. Click `Global Options...`
3. With the "General" (default) screen selected click `Change` where it says "R version:"
4. Select `Use your machine's default version of R64 (64-bit)`
5. Click `OK`
6. Allow RStudio to restart

Comment: Can I install 64bit applications if I'm using 32bit O/S?

Comment: There is a package called bigmemory.How can I use this?

Comment: @Alanq I'm not sure about 64bit R and 32bit Ubuntu, but -- while, yes, you can run some 64-bit apps on 32-bit OS's -- it usually removes the benefit of being able to use more RAM with your app. Using `bigmemory` won't remove the limitations of using 32-bit R but perhaps it will store your data more efficiently. Here's the reference manual: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigmemory/bigmemory.pdf  I would recommend that you just use a 64-bit OS, perhaps via VirtualBox or just installing it (a pain I know, but having a 64-bit OS will make life easier).  http://www.viva64.com/en/k/0004/

Comment: Thank you for your help I think I'll install a 64bit of O/S to avoid any future problems.